# Xamarin.iOS - PIE warning

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

We just submitted a new Xamarin.iOS app to the app store, and received this warning from Apple:

```
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "My App". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: 

Non-PIE Binary - The executable 'MyApp.app' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information, refer to:
```

[Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1788/_index.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013354)

```
If you would like to update your binary for this app, you can reject this binary from the Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting your binary will remove your app from the review queue and the review process will start over from the beginning when you resubmit your binary.
```

I'm guessing Apple recently started enforcing this.

Is this something I can turn on in Xamarin Studio? Will it cause any issues with Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK it's **not** enforced yet:

> but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery

The message looks identical to the *old* warning since Apple started encouraging PIE support *about* a month ago.

The latest 6.3.x beta releases already has support for PIE (turned on by default) and the next stable will have it too.

Comment: 6.3.7 has it enabled by default

Comment: Where can the setting be found?

Comment: @Kirk It's **enabled** by default in 6.3.7+ (including 6.4.x stables). The feature can be enabled/disabled by adding `-pie[=VALUE]` to the **Additional mtouch arguments** in the **iOS Build** options.